# Can’t install test app on self hosted Shopware 6 shop

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I’m trying to install my custom app on self-hosted shopware 6 shop. I’m using shopware version 6.4.20.2.

I can’t understand why I can’t install test app. Look indo SW docs and it telling me, that app must be installed in such way…

I’ve created app in custom/apps/ and placed there manifest.xml file. So my app consist of one manifest file: custom/apps/MyExampleApp/manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/shopware/trunk/src/Core/Framework/App/Manifest/Schema/manifest-2.0.xsd">
    <meta>
        <name>MyExampleApp</name>
        <label>Test label to MyExampleApp</label>
        <label lang="de-DE">Test label DE to MyExampleApp</label>
        <description>Test description to MyExampleApp.</description>
        <description lang="de-DE">Test description DE to MyExampleApp.</description>
        <author>Test Developer</author>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <license>MIT</license>
    </meta>
</manifest>
```

Now I’m trying to install it with bin/console app:install --activate MyExampleApp and getting error

> [INFO] Could not find any app with this name

I can't understand why SW6 shop can't see my app. All caches deleted...

Comment: Try `bin/console plugin:refresh` first, maybe your app is not loaded yet.

Comment: @kiplingi `plugin:refresh` will refresh only plugins, not apps. There's a command `bin/console app:refresh` - but it doesn't show my plugin in the list...

Comment: app:refresh is more like plugin:update. I had instances where plugin:refresh helped discovering apps.

Comment: @kiplingi no luck. app still invisible :(

Answer (score 0):

To create an app you need a valid `manifest.xml` with all the required fields. Currently the XML element `<copyright>` is missing. After adding this element the App should install correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<manifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/shopware/trunk/src/Core/Framework/App/Manifest/Schema/manifest-2.0.xsd">
    <meta>
        <name>MyExampleApp</name>
        <label>Test label to MyExampleAppddd</label>
        <label lang="de-DE">Test label DE to MyExampleApp</label>
        <description>Test description to MyExampleApp.</description>
        <description lang="de-DE">Test description DE to MyExampleApp.</description>
        <copyright>(c) by shopware AG</copyright>
        <author>Test Developer</author>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <license>MIT</license>
    </meta>
</manifest>
```

Install App: `bin/console app:install MyExampleApp -a`